# How to version control overlapping folder structures?

Tags: ios, git, unity-game-engine, plugins, version-control

Been thinking on this for ages, really interested in any suggestions.

A **simple Unity game project** looks like this, with a Git repo at `Root`.

```
Root
├─Assets
│ └─Game files
└─Project files
```

As I develop numerous plugins over time, the **resulting structure** will look like this.

```
Root
├─Assets
│ ├─Plugins
│ │ ├─Plugin_A
│ │ ├─Plugin_B
│ │ ├─Plugin_C
│ │ └─Plugin_D
│ └─Game files
├─iOS Plugin projects
│ └─Plugin_C project
├─Anroid Plugin projects
│ └─Plugin_D project
└─Project files
```

Now I really want to have the plugins their own versioning (so I can keep developing them "from" any game project), also preserve relative project locations for each.

The point is: **To have multiple** (!) **subfolders in the same** (!) **subrepository**. Like having `Assets/Plugins/Plugin_D` and `Anroid Plugin projects/Plugin_D project` in a single (!) subrepository. And do the rest with `Plugin_C`, etc.

Would be great to have a repository of each plugin at root (preserving their subfolder location).

```
Root
└─Assets
  └─Plugins
    └─Plugin_A
```

But the point is to have overlapping folders in the same (!) plugin repository. Like have a repository, containing native plugins (`Assets/Plugins/Plugin_C`) and (!) containing their respective overlapping plugin projects (`iOS Plugin projects/Plugin_C project`). Like this for iOS:

```
Root
├─Assets
│ └─Plugins
│   └─Plugin_C
└─iOS Plugin projects
  └─Plugin_C project
```

And for Android:

```
Root
├─Assets
│ └─Plugins
│   └─Plugin_D
└─Anroid Plugin projects
  └─Plugin_D project
```

I tried to make them all **submodules** of the project root (with ignoring everything but the plugin folders), but I could not create multiply submodules into a single `Root` folder.

As a bonus, it would be great to have all the plugins in a single repository, so I could bootstrap any project easily, then add / remove modules selectively.

---

What I have so far is to make each folder a submodule locally, but this way a project setup process is really tedious / error prone, also I cannot version the native plugin projects with their respective managed counterpart.

Really interested in any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a good use of .gitignore: the main project root ignores the X_Plugin_projects directories, then each of *those* directories would be their own git repos.

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks for the suggestion! I could do the same simply with submodules, but I cannot version the overlapping folder structure that way (see the iOS plugin content above).

Comment: Yeah, I dunno for those.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manage plugin A to D in separate repositories. But if these four plugins are related you’d better manage them in a repo for four branches.

Then you can use **`git subtree`** to add plugins for the subfolders which you want to apply for your projects.

Such as If you want to add Plugin_C in `Assets/Plugins`, you can use:

```
git subtree add --prefix=Assets/Plugins/Plugin_C <URL for pluginC repo> master
```

If you want add plugin_D to `Android/`, you can use:

```
git subtree add --prefix=Android/Plugin_D <URL for pluginD repo> master
```

Comment: The method can also used for the repo are separate. And I updated my answer, you can have a try.

Comment: There also have `git subtree pull` and `git subtree push`, so that you can updatethe plugin in subfolders or you can push it to plugin repo :)

Comment: submodule is to use a repo as component of your main repo. But for your situation, you need to reuse plugins(more then once) for your projects, so sutree is more light-weight and flexible to use. There is no better between submodule and subtree, but more suitable for different situations.

Comment: Yes, same parent but different subfolders is OK. You can add multiple plugins by subtree.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: I just can't add subtree (containing some plugin folders) to the project root. There is always a `--prefix` is needed.

Comment: We were talking about add the code of another repo branch to your current repo subfolders. And git subtree add need prefix option. If you need to add files to the root of your current repo, you can move the files from subfolder to the root.

Comment: Sorry, but you seem ignore the point of my question. I know I can add sumbodules and subtrees for any subfolder, this is how they are working by default. This thing does not make a question on Stack Overflow. What I wanted to know, is that if I can put multiple subfolders of the same root to multiple repositories. Like to put `Assets/Plugins/Plugin_D` and (!) `Anroid Plugin projects/Plugin_D project` into a single (!) subrepository. And do the same with the rest of the plugins. Which I seemingly cannot. I tried numerous repository setup, each one complained about already existing repos.

Comment: Updated the question to add emphasis on this part. Probably it was easy to miss.